# AWS SES forward bounces, complaints, and/or deliveries using SNS notification in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I'm really confuse about how to setup the Amazon SES email's statuses ;***bounces, complaints, and/or deliveries*** with **node.js** to be forwarded with `SNS`. I tried following their [Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-sns-notifications.html)

1. I first created a Topic in SNS
2. I went to the sender's email, in the Notification tab to forward the bounces/complaints and deliveries to that created Topic.
3. Then I tried to subscribe to that topic in Node.js

So first issue here is that I don't know what to put as an `EndPoint` in the following piece of code *(I ended up putting the SNS endpoint of the region I was using)*:

```
    let AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.loadFromPath('config.json');

    const sns:AWS.SNS = new AWS.SNS();
        //subscribe to particular topic
        let params:any = {
            Protocol: 'https', /* required */   //http , https ,application
            TopicArn: 'arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:528353458268:email-notification', /* required */   // topic you want to subscribe
            Endpoint: 'https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com' // the endpoint that you want to receive notifications.
        };

        sns.subscribe(params, function(err:any, data:any) {
            if (err){
                console.log(err);
            }
            else{
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

From that, I received this object:

```
 { ResponseMetadata: { RequestId: 'badd5d44-6ac5-55a0-92d6-0c8d7c6ad14c' },
   SubscriptionArn: 'pending confirmation' }
```

So I was wondering if i'm doing something wrong here and how can I confirm the `subscription` to the topic? I though it would be automatic...

Comment: The `Endpoint` there a URL pointing to your server that will receive the notification. For example you can create an endpoint on called 'http://yoursite.com/bounce' and give that to SNS. Every time there is a bounce your server will get a call at that location. You can set up what type of http request SNS will send.

Comment: See the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36958160/how-to-confirm-subscribe-and-get-sns-notifications-at-a-http-endpoint

Comment: Your `Endpoint` needs to exist as an exposed Expressjs route (assuming Express since you mention Node). You need to handle the incoming request `Type=SubscriptionConfirmation` once you set up the subscription in the SNS console. You then capture the SubscribeURL sent in this request and navigate to the URL this key provides. Before you follow this advice, I recommend you have a look at my answer, this is just one of many steps to get you where you want to be.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation is tough to work through, I went through this myself and wrote a post on exactly this using Nodejs/Expressjs.

Unfortunately, this topic is not trivial and it would be impossible to explain all the steps in this answer.

https://trentmillar.github.io/amazon-ses-email/2016/12/23/amazon-ses-notifications-sent-to-httphttps-service-using-sns-and-nodejs